# How to 3D plot a 2 parameter function that includes a definitive integral, using Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: wolframalpha, wolfram-language

I'm trying to plot the following function using Wolfram Alpha:

[image: 1]

I have used the [following](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%28x%5E2+%E2%88%92+%28+Integrate+sqrt%281+%E2%88%92+t%29+%29+%2C+for+x+from+0+to+5%2C+for+y+from+-4+to+1%29) natural language query:

```
plot (x^2 − ( Integrate sqrt(1 − t) ) , for x from 0 to 5, for y from -4 to 1)
```

I'm struggling to add in the boundaries for the definitive integral.

What's the correct query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried several different ways and can't yet get WA to do it in one step.

But I can get it to do it in two steps.

First

```
x^2-Integrate sqrt(1-t),{t,0,y}
```

returns

```
x^2+2/3((1-y)^(3/2)-1) for Re(y)<=1 or y not element R
```

and your range for y satisfies that condition

Next

```
plot x^2+2/3((1-y)^(3/2)-1),{x,0,5},{y,-4,1}
```

and it appears you are done